# XML-RPC.NET with two different results in the same method

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

I need to consume a XML-RPC server with a method that return different types depending on the success or failure of the process.

Right now I´m using the xml-rpc lib from http://xml-rpc.net/

My proxy looks like this:

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://someURL/")]
public interface IAccount : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("create_account")]
    ReturnStatusResult CreateFreeAccount(FreeAccount account);
}
```

Where ReturnStatusResult is:

```
 public class ReturnStatusResult
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

    public ReturnStatusDetail[] detail { get; set; }
}
```

And ReturnStatusDetail:

```
   public class ReturnStatusDetail
{
    public string codigo_erro { get; set; }
    public string[] campo_nome { get; set; }
    public string[] campo_valor { get; set; }
    public string[] campo_tipo { get; set; }
    public string[] campo_tamanho { get; set; }
    public string[] campo_obrigatorio { get; set; }
    public string[] campo_erro { get; set; }
}
```

If the call to CreateFreeAccount is successfull, the server will return ReturnStatusDetail[].
But if the CreateFreeAccount fail, the return will be a ReturnStatusResult.

All that been said, anyone knows a way to solve this?

I tried to look in a way to postpone the the type binding by setting the CreateFreeAccount return type to an object, but I couldn't find the xml-rpc.net parser method.

Comment: Do you control the creation of such response? I mean... That's just solvable with code = codigo_erro status variable and the message, and having just one type. The response always returns at least 1 item in the array (no matter if it is a success or a fail).

Comment: No, unfortunately I don´t have any control over the response. This is provided by a external server.